# IOS APNs p12 certifcate files is not working with Java

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications, ssl-certificate, bouncycastle, jks

I am trying to use https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns APNs push library for pushing notifications from server.

The customer provided a APNs p12 file which is not working with this library and some other JAVA tools also

To investigate it, I tried to use http://portecle.sourceforge.net/

It tries to use mutiple combination for BKS, JKS, UBER....etc and give errors like

```
java.io.IOException: exception decrypting data - java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
    org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKPKCS12KeyStore.cryptData(Unknown Source)

java.io.IOException: Wrong version of key store.
    org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)

java.io.IOException: Wrong version of key store.
    org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyStore$BouncyCastleStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
```

I tried to import the customer provided p12 to my Mac laptop KeyChain and then I exported again as new p12 file, then it works fine.

But the customer supposed to configure the certificate uploads from his side using some API, we cannot do this manually everytime

How can we solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE). The built-in security providers (/lib/bin/security) don't allow higher security ciphers.

Java 6:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html

Java 7:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

Java 8:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Comment: shouldn't affect bouncycastle, does it?

Comment: Underneath BouncyCastle relies on those settings, too. You can do some hackish things around that. But the easiest way is to just replace the two standard jar files with those from the JCE.